# How to fix: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

When I execute this piece of code, it doesn't work. It is returning:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null.

But, when I use the string arguments directly from the inside the function, it works.

I have tried and failed to pass arguments to queryselector in function parameters.

```js
window.onload = changeText('lap0015', 'General Physics I')

function changeText(subject) {
  document.querySelector(`#${subject} > .name`).innerHTML = `${name}`
  console.log('OK!')
}
```

```html
<div id="lap0015" class="subject">
  <p class="code"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="theory"></p>
  <p class="practice"></p>
  <p class="totalHourLoad"></p>
</div>


// **After** some tries, I changed my script to jQuery:

const name = 'Física Geral I'
const code = 'lap0015'

$(document).ready(getText)

function getText() {
$(`#${code} > p.code`).text(`${code}`)
$(`#${code} > p.name`).text(`${name}`)
}
```

How do I programmatically pass arguments to getText, when there's no parenthesis in `.ready(getText 'here')`?

The actual result of this is the error given above. Expected result should be as this:

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO4xq.jpg)

Comment: Which browser are you getting that error in?

Comment: Firefox 68.0.2 (64-bits)

Comment: Still not working. Tried in Chrome and Firefox. In Chrome we have a little more long answer:
```
script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at changeText (script.js:4)
    at script.js:1
changeText @ script.js:4
(anonymous) @ script.js:1
```

Comment: That means, that at the time of execution, `document.querySelector("#lap0015 > .name")` cannot find the element. Replace that line with `console.log(!!document.getElementById("lap0015"))` and tell us the result.

Comment: after lots of tries, i've decided to get away from vanilla JS and used JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(() => getText('lap0015', 'General Physics I'));
```

Or (If you need to support IE):

```
$(document).ready(function() { getText('lap0015', 'General Physics I'); });
```

Comment: this is an example of anonymous function? or functional paradigm, or maybe a closure? Works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: now can i substitute the strings inside getText for parsed JSON data? I have a Json file in this directory with all data for all subjects in my course. In time: the repository is in GIthub and is public. github.com/vlaskz/dependency-chart

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to recreate your error, but I've got your code working. I only had to add the missing `name` parameter to the `changeText` function.

```js
window.onload = changeText('lap0015', 'General Physics I')

function changeText(subject, name) {
  document.querySelector(`#${subject} > .name`).innerHTML = `${name}`
  console.log('OK!')
}
```

```html
<div id="lap0015" class="subject">
  <p class="code"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="theory"></p>
  <p class="practice"></p>
  <p class="totalHourLoad"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeText` function needs to accept a 2nd parameter `name`:

```js
window.onload = changeText('lap0015', 'General Physics I')

function changeText(subject, name) {
  document.querySelector(`#${subject} > .name`).innerHTML = name;
  console.log('OK!')
}
```

```html
<div id="lap0015" class="subject">
  <p class="code"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="theory"></p>
  <p class="practice"></p>
  <p class="totalHourLoad"></p>
</div>
```